# Upload file with json object using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to upload file with JSON object. I am using retrofit2, but I get 400 Bad request. 
My request example using curl:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8082/attachment -F filename=37.pdf -F 'data={"DocumentTypeID":2, "DocumentID":1, "Description":"описание","AttachmentTypeId":2}'
```

Also I made request in postman and it also works:
[image]

My Java Code:

```
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse(getMimeType(path)),
                        file
                );

        MultipartBody.Part body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename", file.getName(), requestFile);

        FileDescriptionObject fdo = new FileDescriptionObject();
        fdo.setDescription("test");
        fdo.setDocumentId(fileModel.Id);
        fdo.setDocumentTypeId(1);
        fdo.setAttachmentTypeId(2);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String ds1 = gson.toJson(fdo);

        RequestBody description =
                RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse("text/plain"), ds1);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = activity.getAsyncHelper().getWebService().postFile(
                "http://localhost:8082/attachment",
                body,
                description);
```

My API:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST
    Call<ResponseBody> postFile(@Url String url,
                                @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                @Part("data")RequestBody data);
```

My logs:

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://localhost:8082/attachment
          Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=520da8f2-5fac-4567-be0f-61618cc881bd
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 468
D/OkHttp: --520da8f2-5fac-4567-be0f-61618cc881bd
D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="4.pdf"
          Content-Type: application/pdf
          Content-Length: 3
          323
          --520da8f2-5fac-4567-be0f-61618cc881bd
          Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"
          Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
          Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
          Content-Length: 77
          {"AttachmentTypeId":2,"Description":"test","DocumentId":4,"DocumentTypeId":1}
          --520da8f2-5fac-4567-be0f-61618cc881bd--
          --> END POST (468-byte body)
```

Maybe the problem is in this additional headers from json data? I think so because in postman they are not added.

Comment: Not sure it is the issue, but as you are sending a Json with your image, have you tried using `application/json` or  `multipart/form-data` instead of `text/plain` when creating the `RequestBody description` ?

Comment: yes, I tried both of them

Comment: why are you passing `@Url String url`?, are you not using base api with all calls?

Comment: Yes, I am using different Url from base api url

Comment: is your api allowing to upload only text files? can you check that.

Comment: I can upload any file

Comment: application/pdf. Path is correct too

Comment: can you try adding `@Header("Content-Type") String content_type,` to your call and setting its value to `"application/json"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), ds1);
```

to

```
MultipartBody.Part description = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("data", ds1);
```

and see if that works. Also change you API call to

```
@Multipart
@POST
Call<ResponseBody> postFile(@Url String url,
                            @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                            @Part MultipartBody.Part data);
```

Comment: It is working! Can you please explain why it behaves different?

Comment: I'm not much of an expert on Retrofit/OkHttp, but basically when defining an API call with `@MultiPart`, it is best to make sure all the `@Part` parameters are of type `MultipartBody.Part` to avoid any problems with the format of the request body.